# JMeter TCP sampler to send hex data.Data getting converted in server

Tags: jmeter

I am using TCP Sampler in JMeter. The data being sent is in the HEX format (`24 00 0F CD 04 39 40 00 23`). I am getting data in server but data getting converting into some other format. Actually I should get this data in server `24 00 0F CD 04 39 40 00 23`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, but I think guys will appreciate some more info about your infrastructure client / server, the real data you get on the server, and possibly some source code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) some of your data represents control characters. Try passing values as it described in [How to Send Control Characters Using the JMeter TCP Sampler?](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743676-how-to-send-control-characters-using-the-jmeter-tcp-sampler-) guide.